# How do you watch multiple files, but only run task on changed file, in Grunt.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

In learning how to use [grunt](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt), I am trying to make a simple coffee-script watcher/compiler. The problem is, if I tell the `watch` task to watch several files, and one changes, it is going to pass all of the files to the `coffee` command. This means when you change 1 file, it's going to recompile *all* of the files matching the `src` pattern. Instead, I want to only recompile the single file that changed that matches the `src` pattern.

Here is the `grunt.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    coffee: {
      app: {
        src: ['test/cases/controller/*.coffee'],
        dest: 'tmp',
        options: {
          bare: true,
          preserve_dirs: true
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['<config:coffee.app.src>'],
      tasks: ['coffee:app']
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-coffee');
  grunt.registerTask('default', 'coffee');
};
```

This is using [grunt-coffee](https://github.com/avalade/grunt-coffee), which is basically this: https://gist.github.com/2373159.

When I run `grunt watch`, and I save a file in `test/cases/controller/*.coffee`, it compiles *all* of the matching files (putting them in `tmp/*`).

How do you instead *only compile the **changed** file* using grunt?

Answer (score 15):

The upcoming (and currently in-development) v0.4.0a grunt has the [grunt.file.watchFiles](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/devel/docs/api_file.md#gruntfilewatchfiles) object, which was designed expressly for this purpose. The grunt-coffee plugin may have added support for this feature already, I'm not sure.

Either way, if you're interested in trying an in-development version of grunt in your project, check out the [When will I be able to use in-development feature 'X'?](https://github.com/cowboy/grunt/blob/master/docs/faq.md#when-will-i-be-able-to-use-in-development-feature-x-%E2%9A%91) FAQ entry.

Comment: Yeah, so this doesn't exist anymore, and this is  still being discussed.  Watch https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/14

Comment: This is a problem with node.js in general. Gaze has wrapped this and it is getting close to a fix. see if you can help. https://github.com/shama/gaze/issues/14

Comment: Anyone new to this feature should look here for more info on "watch" -> https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch

Answer (score 8):

I got this working when compiling my less files. You should be able to mess with this configuration a little bit to git it working with the coffeescript plugin. The portion of interest is the `grunt.event.on('watch', ...)`. In this event handler I'm updating the `files` property in the less command to only contain the changed file.

```
path = require('path');

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          paths: ["./library/less"],
        },
        files: [
          { src: "./library/less/bootstrap.less", dest: "./library/css/bootstrap.css"},
          { src: "./library/less/app.less", dest: "./library/css/app.css"}
        ]
      }
    },

    watch: {
      styles: {
        files: "./library/less/*",
        tasks: ["less"],
        options: {
          nospawn: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });

  // Event handling
  grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath){
    // Update the config to only build the changed less file.
    grunt.config(['less', 'development', 'files'], [
      {src: filepath, dest: './library/css/' + path.basename(filepath, '.less') + '.css'}
    ]);
  });

  // Load the plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  // Tasks
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

Comment: This method doesn't work with [building files dynamically](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically). Any workarounds?

Comment: @blachniet: This is great! But I still got a problem - maybe you know the answer to it. Is it possible to overwrite a single property of the options? So for example within the watch event handler I use "grunt.config(['sftp', 'widgets', 'options.srcBasePath'], file_path);". I was hoping to use the options I already set in the sftp config but add a single key value pair to it. Is that possible? With my code above nothing happens. With "grunt.config(['sftp', 'widgets', 'options'], {"srcBasePath:":file_path});" all other options are overwritten...

Comment: @blachniet: Nevermind^^ - grunt.config(['sftp', 'widgets', 'options', 'srcBasePath'], file_path); worked for setting a single key value pair. ;)

Answer (score 4):

None of these answers worked very well for me. Here is my solution if anyone is interested (I know I'm a little late in replying to this question).

https://gist.github.com/ryansmith94/8569178

Comment: Never too late to post a correct answer -- things are always changing.

Answer (score 3):

In this [issue](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/22#issuecomment-15871732), Kyle Robinson suggests using the `watch`event. It's very important to set watch task `nospawn` property to `true` to make it work. I modified his solution to selectively run the tasks:

```
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
    if (minimatch(filepath, grunt.config('watch.stylesheets.files'))) {
        grunt.config('compass.dist.options.specify', [filepath]);
    }

    if (minimatch(filepath, grunt.config('watch.scripts.files'))) {
        var uglifySrc = filepath.replace(grunt.config('uglify.dist.cwd'), '');
        grunt.config('jshint.dist.src', [filepath]);
        grunt.config('uglify.dist.src', [uglifySrc]);
    }
});
```

Here is the complete solution: https://gist.github.com/luissquall/5408257

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer looks like exactly for similar tasks:

> Configure Grunt tasks to run with newer files only.
>
> Synopsis: The newer task will configure another task to run with src
>   files that are a) newer than the dest files or b) newer than the last
>   successful run (if there are no dest files). See below for examples
>   and more detail.

You can prepend easily to any task. In your case:

```
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');
  grunt.registerTask('default', 'newer:coffee');
```

Comment: The newer plugin works really well for me... and it is fast.

Answer (score 2):

So new to Grunt 0.4 is more named tasks

Let us give you an example!

```
watch: {
    package1: {
        files: [
            './modules/package1/**/*.coffee'
        ],
        tasks: ['coffee:package3']
    },
    package2: {
        files: [
            './test_packages/package2/**/*.coffee'
        ],
        tasks: ['coffee:package3']
    },
    package3: {
        files: [
            './test_packages/package3/**/*.coffee'
        ],
        tasks: ['coffee:package3']
    },
}
```

To run all those watch tasks, simply do
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['myInitialBuild', 'watch']);

Where `myInitialBuild` is whatever initial build (all of the files) then follow it up with a watch on each package.  In reality you could do this for every file but that sounds sucky.

Answer (score 2):

The task grunt-contrib-watch now supports this.

https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-contrib-watch -> look for "Compiling Files As Needed"

```
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    scripts: {
      files: ['lib/*.js'],
      tasks: ['jshint'],
      options: {
        nospawn: true,
      },
    },
  },
  jshint: {
    all: ['lib/*.js'],
  },
});

// on watch events configure jshint:all to only run on changed file
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
  grunt.config(['jshint', 'all'], filepath);
});
```

This should prevent the tasks from compiling all files every time when something changes.

Comment: For how long does the new value set with `grunt.config(['jshint', 'all'], filepath);` take effect? Does it revert back to the previous setting after the task is complete?