# Operating on modified files in grunt task

Tags: gruntjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you watch multiple files, but only run task on changed file, in Grunt.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063266/how-do-you-watch-multiple-files-but-only-run-task-on-changed-file-in-grunt-js)

Inside a task, say a coffeescript compiler, how do I retrieve the exact files which got changed so that I can only selectively compile only those files rather than having to compile my entire code-base.

Comment: I guess you refer to  `watch` task of Grunt, then [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063266/how-do-you-watch-multiple-files-but-only-run-task-on-changed-file-in-grunt-js) might be what you look for.

Comment: Thank you. I hadn't seen that question before. That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I will close the question as a duplicate.