# Running grunt-contrib-jshint only on recently modified files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, jshint

We're going through refactoring the code on a very large site. I would like to enforce linting on any files that get changed, but ignore the rest (as many of them will end up being removed so it's a waste of time to tidy them up).

I would like to have a grunt task that checks that a file's modified date is more recent than its created (*fetched from repo) date and lints it if this is the case (would be good also to have grunt update a json list of files to be linted).

I haven't used node much apart from grunt and its plugins. I'm going to use http://gruntjs.com/creating-tasks as a starting point, but could someone sketch out for me how I might approach writing this task, in particular any considerations to do with asynchronisity.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple options:

1 - You can use a [custom filter function](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function) to filter the list of files returned by your jshint file pattern. Something like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  var fs = require('fs');

  var myLibsPattern = ['./mylibs/**/*.js'];

  // on linux, at least, ctime is not retained after subsequent modifications,
  // so find the date/time of the earliest-created file matching the filter pattern
  var creationTimes = grunt.file.expand( myLibsPattern ).map(function(f) { return new Date(fs.lstatSync(f).ctime).getTime() });
  var earliestCreationTime = Math.min.apply(Math, creationTimes);
  // hack: allow for 3 minutes to check out from repo
  var filterSince = (new Date(earliestCreationTime)).getTime() + (3 * 60 * 1000);

  grunt.initConfig({
    options: {
      eqeqeq: true,
      eqnull: true
    },
    jshint: {
      sincecheckout: {
        src: myLibsPattern,
        // filter based on whether it's newer than our repo creation time
        filter: function(filepath) {
          return (fs.lstatSync(filepath).mtime > filterSince);
        },
      },
    },
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint']);
};
```

2 - use the [grunt-contrib-watch plugin](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) to detect when files are changing. Then you can read the list of files from the event, as described in [this comment](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) by Kyle Robinson Young ("shama"):

```
grunt.initConfig({
  watch: {
    all: {
      files: ['<%= jshint.all.src %>'],
      tasks: ['jshint'],
      options: { nospawn: true }
    }
  },
  jshint: { all: { src: ['Gruntfile.js', 'lib/**/*.js'] } }
});
// On watch events, inject only the changed files into the config
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
  grunt.config(['jshint', 'all', 'src'], [filepath]);
});
```

This doesn't **exactly** meet your requirements since it depends on having the watch running as soon as you start modifying files, but it might fit better with the overall Grunt approach.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063266/how-do-you-watch-multiple-files-but-only-run-task-on-changed-file-in-grunt-js) but beware some of it relates to older version of Grunt and to coffeescript.

**UPDATE:** there's now a [grunt-newer](https://github.com/tschaub/grunt-newer) plugin which handles all this in a more elegant way

Comment: Very nice approach bro! Will surely try it out when possible.

Comment: It does rely on developers running watch though, so developers not running watch won't be compelled to lint anything. But I might still consider it as an option

Comment: @wheresrhys updated with another option. Code might not be perfect but should give you the concept.

Comment: Thanks - your method for getting the earliest created time was the missing piece in how I was thinking of approaching this

Answer (score 1):

Use [grunt-newer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-newer) for this. 
It is especially made to configure Grunt tasks to run with newer files only.

Example:

```
grunt.initConfig({
  jshint: {
    options: {
      jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
    },
    all: {
      src: 'src/**/*.js'
    }
  }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-newer');

grunt.registerTask('lint', ['newer:jshint:all']);
```