# In grunt, if I'm watching multiple files and two or more change, how can I only run tasks on the changed files?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I've got an `initConfig` with this code in it:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    watch: {
        options: {
            spawn: false
        },
        coffee: {
            files: [
                'src/**/*.coffee'
            ],
            tasks: ['coffee', 'coffeelint', 'concat', 'qunit']
        },

...
    coffee: {
        glob_to_multiple: {
            expand: true,
            flatten: false,
            cwd: '.',
            src: ['src/**/*.coffee'],
            ext: '.js'
        }
    },

...

grunt.event.on('watch', function (action, filepath) {
    if (grunt.file.isMatch("**/*.coffee", filepath)) {
        grunt.config(['coffee', 'glob_to_multiple', 'src'], filepath);
    }
});
```

This is supposed to compile only the .coffee files that have changed.  This works *pretty* well.  But I just noticed that if I modify multiple at once, it will output this:

```
Waiting...src\test\resources\app\js\FILE1.coffee
src\main\resources\app\js\FILE2.coffee
OK
>> File "src\test\resources\app\js\FILE1.coffee" changed.
>> File "src\main\resources\app\js\FILE2.coffee" changed.


Running "coffee:glob_to_multiple" (coffee) task
File src/main/resources/app/js/FILE2.js created.

...
```

As you can see, I've changed two files, but it's only running the tasks on "FILE2.js".  How can I avoid this?  I want it to run `coffee:glob_to_multiple` on FILE1 and FILE2, not just one of them.

---

NOTE: I'm pretty sure [the documentation](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch) explains how to do this:

> If you save multiple files simultaneously you may opt for a more robust method:

```
var changedFiles = Object.create(null);
var onChange = grunt.util._.debounce(function() {
  grunt.config(['jshint', 'all'], Object.keys(changedFiles));
  changedFiles = Object.create(null);
}, 200);
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
  changedFiles[filepath] = action;
  onChange();
});
```

Following that documentation, I made this change to my code:

```
var changedFiles = Object.create(null);
var onChange = grunt.util._.debounce(function() {
    grunt.config(['coffee', 'glob_to_multiple', 'src'], Object.keys(changedFiles));
    changedFiles = Object.create(null);
}, 200);
grunt.event.on('watch', function(action, filepath) {
    if (grunt.file.isMatch("**/*.coffee", filepath)) {
        changedFiles[filepath] = action;
        onChange();
    }
});
```

And things worked exactly the way I want.  **But I'm not sure how this works.  Could someone explain it to me?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you watch multiple files, but only run task on changed file, in Grunt.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12063266/how-do-you-watch-multiple-files-but-only-run-task-on-changed-file-in-grunt-js)

Comment: @SindreSorhus no it isn't.  The difference here is this is about running a task when **multiple files** have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a pretty sophisticated solution using Lo-Dash debounce ;-) (in a sec...)

Know that when you used your older code of:

```
 grunt.config(['coffee', 'glob_to_multiple', 'src'], filepath);
```

Grunt is instructed to run the coffee task with the new file. The problem with this is that it's a synchronic process and so when another file is changed ( usually this happens in a matter of milliseconds) then Grunt Watch won't allow you to run another process until the **debounceDelay** has been reached.

The default **debounceDelay** is 500 ms, but this can be changed using options of the watch task. (read more **[About option.debounceDelay](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch)**

Basically when you save multiple files, as you saw - only the first file saved is changed. In order to bypass this, a great utility for delaying (debouncing) function run is in the **grunt.util._.debounce** (Lo-Dash link to it is **[here](http://lodash.com/docs#debounce)**

The function's parameters are:

```
_.debounce(func, wait, options)
```

So it takes in the function, how many ms to wait, and some options (that we don't need here).

When you call the **debounce** utility it will delay the execution of the function the waitTime and that way - when you save multiple files at once - all the calls will add up to a single function call after those 200ms time period.

That way - the most useful line here, besides the **debounce** util is the following:

```
changedFiles[filepath] = action;
```

Which will add the files to the (at first) empty object of changedFiles. Notice that after the debounce function has launched we reset the changedFiles obj so that the next call will contain only freshly changed files.

Amazing solution indeed ;-)

Comment: Cool, thanks for the answer.  I didn't know that was a lodash call which prevented me from learning.  IMO the watch api's config should do this out of the box.  It should have an `options: {runTaskOnOnlyChangedFiles: true}`.

Comment: actually grunt-contrib-watch has plenty of more work to be done on it... You can contribute that and suggest they add it to the next release [https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch)

Comment: I think someone's already asked for it: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/149